# saveAll() not saving associated data when created in beforeSave

Tags: php, cakephp, save, associations, cakephp-2.4

Below is the association, the save call, and the data going to the save.  It generates the `UPDATE` query for `Event`, but there are no queries generated to save the associated `EventInstance`.

The `EventInstance` data is created in the Event's beforeSave().

It says it's saving fine - no validation errors..etc.  And I have no validation array on the EventInstance model anyway.  I also checked and my table doesn't have any issues as far as fields not allowing null...etc. - I tested by setting everything as allow null.

I have no idea - this should be so simple - I've done it 500 times before, but for this one, I'm apparently missing something.

```
// Event model --------------------------
public $hasMany = array(
    'EventInstance' => array(
        'dependent' => true,
        'order'     => 'start ASC',
    ),
    ...

// Save call in Event model -------------
    $this->saveAll($data);

// $data ------------------------- 
'Event' => array(
    'id' => 'xxxxxxxx-65b4-4a75-ba4a-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'repeat_type' => '1',
    'repeat_interval' => '2',
    'repeat_weekdays' => 'ns',
    'repeat_on' => '1',
    'repeat_on_weekday' => '',
    'repeat_on_day' => '1',
    'repeat_end' => '',
    'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
    'times' => '',
    'modified' => '2013-11-02 01:07:27',
    'start' => '2013-11-03 01:36:00',
    'end' => '2013-11-10 05:36:00',
    'start_utc' => '2013-11-03 05:36:00',
    'end_utc' => '2013-11-10 10:36:00'
),
'EventInstance' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'start' => '2013-11-05 01:11:00',
        'end' => '2013-11-05 05:36:00'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'start' => '2013-11-07 01:11:00',
        'end' => '2013-11-07 05:36:00'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'start' => '2013-11-09 01:11:00',
        'end' => '2013-11-09 05:36:00'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'start' => '2013-11-11 01:11:00',
        'end' => '2013-11-11 05:36:00'
    )
)
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is a missing `)` for your `public $hasMany = array(` (as closing) you're showing `...` is that's what in there along with other info not posted?

Comment: Are you using innodb as a storage engine?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's not a syntax error - just didn't want write all my associations out here.

Comment: @BarryChapman - I don't know, but if it's not even trying the query, I'm not sure that would matter.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I kind of had my doubts about that.

Comment: What data are you trying to save? Try this: $this->saveAll($data['EventInstance']);

Comment: Cake should handle the association automatically

Comment: @BarryChapman Trying to save the Event data and all it's EventInstances - yes - it SHOULD handle automatically, but it's not.

Comment: @Dave Yes that's why I deleted the comment.

Comment: if your database table doesnt support transactions it will not execute it. Thats why I asked you if you are using InnoDB

Comment: The only other possibility is a problem with your association

Comment: @BarryChapman - my association is listed - I don't see a problem, but that's why I'm asking here.  Even when I literally just list 'EventInstance' without any extras, it still doesn't save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the trigger to save associated data when you call `saveAll()` has already passed by the time the `beforeSave()` adds the new associated data.

So - I just changed my `beforeSave()`s to `beforeValidate()`s, and it works.

Comment: Good Lord! How did you even trace that back?!! Wasted over an hour just to figure out whatever the f*** was happening to my modified [associated] data!!

Comment: Also found [this issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1765) on same topic. Alternative solution would be to do stuff in associated model's `beforeSave()`. Yet another solution could be to override your `saveAll()` in model, something that I never like to do (personal preference). Of course there are several other solutions like using `Cake Events` or `afterSave()` but those are just overkill.